# GameObject doesn't contain a definition for SetActive();

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I was working on a little UI script, when suddenly Unity throw this error:

```
Assets\UI\Menu\MenuUIManager.cs(91,36): error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'SetActive' and no accessible extension method 'SetActive' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

before it worked fine, I wasn't touching the class in a while, so I might have changed it using directions or something like that without noticing (I was working on a Scriptable Object before the error appeared multiple times). I have also set the External tools to VisualStudio 2022 (the correct version) I already tried to switch that, in order to try to fix the errors.

(Unity Also throws the error that GameObject doesn't contain a definition of GetComponent<>(); or .transform)

Can I just Re-import my Scripts or use directions anyhow, or can I regenerate my project files? (already clicked on that button in External tools)

Thanks, help is very appreciated :D
excuse my spelling :)

my code that throws the error is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace EOD
{
    public class MenuUIManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Enums--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //Fields-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private static MenuUIManager instance;

        [Header("Main Menu")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _mainMenuParent;
        private UI_MainMenu _mainMenuUI;

        [Header("Join Private Game")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _joinPrivateGameParent;
        private UI_JoinPrivate _joinPrivateLobbyUI;

        [Header("Customize Character")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _customizeCharacterParent;
        private UI_CustomizeCharacter _customizeCharacterUI;

        [Header("Create Game")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _createGameParent;
        private UI_CreatLobby _creatLobbyUI;

        [Header("LOBBY")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _lobbyParent;
        private UI_Lobby _lobbyUI;

        [Header("Search Game")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _searchGameParent;
        private UI_SearchGame _searchGameUI;

        //Propertys----------------------------------------------------------------------

        //Events-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public delegate void StartGame();
        public event StartGame OnStartGame;

        //Singelton ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static MenuUIManager Instance { get { return instance; } }

        //Unity Functions----------------------------------------------------------------
        private void Awake()
        {
            //Singelton
            if(instance != null && instance != this) { Destroy(this.gameObject); }
            else { instance = this; }

            SetUpReferencesAndEvents();
            SetMainMenuActive();
        }

        //Private/Protected Functions----------------------------------------------------

        private void SetUpReferencesAndEvents()
        {
            _mainMenuUI = _mainMenuParent.GetComponent<UI_MainMenu>();
            _joinPrivateLobbyUI = _joinPrivateGameParent.GetComponent<UI_JoinPrivate>();
            _customizeCharacterUI = _customizeCharacterParent.GetComponent<UI_CustomizeCharacter>();
            _creatLobbyUI = _createGameParent.GetComponent<UI_CreatLobby>();
            _lobbyUI = _lobbyParent.GetComponent<UI_Lobby>();
            _searchGameUI = _searchGameParent.GetComponent<UI_SearchGame>();

        }

        //Public Functions---------------------------------------------------------------
        public void SetMainMenuActive()
        {
            _mainMenuParent.SetActive(true);
            _joinPrivateGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _customizeCharacterParent.SetActive(false);
            _createGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _lobbyParent.SetActive(false);
            _searchGameParent.SetActive(false);
        }
        public void SetJoinPrivateActive()
        {
            _mainMenuParent.SetActive(false);
            _joinPrivateGameParent.SetActive(true);
            _customizeCharacterParent.SetActive(false);
            _createGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _lobbyParent.SetActive(false);
            _searchGameParent.SetActive(false);
        }
        public void SetCustomizeCharacterActive()
        {
            _mainMenuParent.SetActive(false);
            _joinPrivateGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _customizeCharacterParent.SetActive(true);
            _createGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _lobbyParent.SetActive(false);
            _searchGameParent.SetActive(false);
        }
        public void SetCreatLobbyActive()
        {
            _mainMenuParent.SetActive(false);
            _joinPrivateGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _customizeCharacterParent.SetActive(false);
            _createGameParent.SetActive(true);
            _lobbyParent.SetActive(false);
            _searchGameParent.SetActive(false);
        }
        public void SetLobbActive()
        {
            _mainMenuParent.SetActive(false);
            _joinPrivateGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _customizeCharacterParent.SetActive(false);
            _createGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _lobbyParent.SetActive(true);
            _searchGameParent.SetActive(false);
        }
        public void SetSearchGameActive()
        {
            _mainMenuParent.SetActive(false);
            _joinPrivateGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _customizeCharacterParent.SetActive(false);
            _createGameParent.SetActive(false);
            _lobbyParent.SetActive(false);
            _searchGameParent.SetActive(true);
        }
```

As mentioned, I tried the External tool Regenerate Project Files, I tried switching the External Tool from Visual Studio to another IDE, I checked my using directions

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my bad, if anyone ever run in to anything like this, i just had to delete the ScriptableObjects that i wasnt using anymore. i dont exacly know why, but this seemed to had a tail of Errors behind it. i also commented all the "error lines" out, reCompiled by clicking into unity, and the reCommented them in again, and recompiled again, now everything is working just fine :)